An issue with Web services provided by Apache that are not accessible via Nginx reverse proxy into Docker containers
I intend to deploy the website on my server like this image
enter image description here
But when I successfully deployed it and visited it in my browser, it showed that the site did not provide a secure connection
I use the workPress website service provided in the nginx reverse proxy docker container, WorkPress is deployed on the Apache server, but after I configure nginx, I visit the website and it shows that the website does not provide a secure connection
conf

`server {
    listen  443 ssl;
    server_name myserver.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/_.myserver.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/_.myserver.com.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    access_log /var/log/nginx/myserver.com.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_read_timeout 30;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
    }

}`

8080 is the port of the web service mapping in docker
Of course, my nginx is also configured with forwarding
conf

`server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test1.minnuo.group;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}`

I want the effect to be different domains accessing different websites on the same machine
Who can help me?
